Android Studio autocomplete breaks when editing a Kotlin file
I'm using Android Studio to learn how to develop Android apps, and the code completion feature for Kotlin files randomly (?) breaks. For example, when I start typing a variable name and press Ctrl+space to bring up the suggestions window, it says there are no suggestions. I'm using Android Studio 2024.1.2 Patch 1 on Windows 10. I'm not using any plugins that didn't come with Android Studio.
A lot of other people have had similar issues (see links below) and I have tried all the solutions proposed in those threads, for example:

Invalidating the cache and restarting

Turning the Power Saving mode on and off again, and then restarting

Renaming a bunch of folders and restarting

Deleting the .idea folder from the project


Stackoverflow question
Stackoverflow question
The weird thing is, once I've manually typed the variable name and type a period, then the completion works fine and I get a list of suggestions to continue the statement. The autocomplete seems not to work when starting to type on a new line, or when typing argument names in a function call. In addition, after invalidating the caches and restarting, the code completion works fine while Android Studio is indexing the project. As soon as the indexing and Gradle building is finished, it doesn't work anymore.
When I load a different project, the problem disappears. The last time the code completion broke, I was working on creating some UI tests according to the codelab linked below. If I remember correctly, the time before that I was also working on tests, though I cannot imagine this would contribute to the autocomplete breaking.
Android Basics course codelab
Does anybody have a hunch what else I could try? Much appreciated!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Did you try reparing IDE? File -> Repair IDE

Yes I also tried that, went through all the steps ending with the cache invalidation and restart step. Tested after every step and after completing, and it didn't fix the problem unfortunately.
